# Send json object to mysql using jquery/javascript/php?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

I have a page that generates json data from several fields and I want to send it to a mysql database.
I currently have a link, the user clicks the link, the javascript takes the information they've inputed and sends it to a server. Due to the nature, I need all the data in one field in the mysql database. Any ideas?

EDIT:
The data comes from several contenteditable divs, in such a way that there is a specific hierarchy.
Such as

```
Data : {
  Heading : 1,
    info1 : 1,
    info2 : 2,
    info3 : 3
    },{
  Heading : 2,
    info1 : 1,
    info2 : 2,
    info3 : 3
    }
```

Comment: At some point in the future, you or someone you love will realize that storing "all the data in one field in the mysql database" was a *Bad Idea*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) post.  E.g.:

```
$.ajax({
    url: someURL,
    type: 'post',
    data: JSON.stringify(myObj),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data, status, xhr)
    {
       // ...
    }
});
```

To make sure you have JSON.stringify, use [json2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js).  The `contentType` means you are posting a JSON document, the `dataType` means you expect to receive one from the server.

On the server, you use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to decode, and [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to encode a response.

Comment: Thanks, stringify was what I needed. I had never heard of that before.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the "serialize" concept?

In jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

In PHP: http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

So you would take all the input, serialize it via jQuery, send the big string to the server and store in your database as-is? Then later when you retrieve it in php, you can unseralize it.

Comment: `serialize` does *not* output JSON.

Comment: JSON *is* a serialized object.

Comment: but then you can easily unserialize in php and then json_encode, no?