# "leaflet" How do I store and retrieve (search for) markers using a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, database, tooltip, leaflet, markers

I'm having a hard time with this project: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/leaflet-js/Vl56hyRp1i8

I hope you guys can help me with this last step.

There will be hundreds of thousands of markers but only the one you search for will be displayed. The content of the tooltips will have to be submitted through a form. I will not know the position for the markers until the mosaic is rendered.

Once the mosaic is rendered we have the position of the markers and I need to be able to search for any marker (by it's ID) and zoom+pan to it while displaying the marker and it's tooltip.

For example if I want to make a mosaic of 500x500 pictures this is what will happen:

- we wait for users to submit a picture each until we have 250.000 pictures.
- the tooltip meta content will be submitted along with each picture from the users (1 picture for each user) - this is also when the marker ID will be generated
- now that we have 250k pictures we can render the mosaic, after the mosaic is complete I will have a text file containing the name and location of each individual picture by row+column
- I need to use this file to fill in the position of the marker for each user's picture
- I need to be able after this, to display only markers that you search for
- when you search for a marker it will be by it's ID so it will be accurate and also I need the zoom+pan function here
- when you click on a picture (marker) I need for that marker to appear (unhide the tooltip).

If anybody can help me please, this project is very cool and I would hate to get stuck on it. I will give proper credit and stuff. If you are really good I am even considering monetary rewards.

Thanks.

Comment: NEVER STORE HTML IN DB!!

Comment: It's not really HTML, I think it's just plain text mostly, but maybe I need to store an image as well.

Comment: The image will probably only need a link reference stored.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to follow this workflow:

1. For data drawing and editing I use Leaflet plugin [leaflet.draw](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw) - .
2. For store data in GeoJSON format I use Leaflet function toGeoJSON(); like that `var myMarkers = new L.FeatureGroup();
   map.addLayer(myMarkers);
   ....
   // get json
   var myMarkersJson = myMarkers.toGeoJSON();`
3. myMarkersJson I upload to MySQL database and store data as json. You can read more about sending json to MySQL using js/jquery [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199887/send-json-object-to-mysql-using-jquery-javascript-php).
4. For analysis of data I use jQuery parseJSON
5. For uploading json data again to leaflet map, I use Leaflet function geoJSON();

I think this workflow is the easiest way to store, search and display data in leaflet from MySQL. But this solution may not be suitable for big data analysis.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, do you have a practical example of this? I would love to actually see a source code or a detailed tutorial. I don't have a use for leaflet.draw unfortunately, but as I have read so far everyone keeps saying to use json somehow. Not sure how though :|